# Conditional CSS for IE9 not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In my website, I have a table of search results. It is center aligned in Firefox and Chrome but not IE9. I am using the following conditional CSS but apparently it is not working, it is still left aligned in IE9.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.ie9fix {
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    float: center;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

What exactly do I need to change in my code to get the table center aligned?

Comment: And this is working when you take out the conditionals?

Comment: Just remove the `position: absolute`.. And it's really weird that your code needs IE9 fixes - that browser handles CSS pretty well actually

Comment: `float:center`? Are you sure this is correct CSS?

Comment: My apologies, I am a newbie in CSS. It was an attempt for trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need absolute positioning:

```
<style>
.example {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; }
.example > DIV {margin: 0 auto; width: 75%; }
</style>

<div class="example"><div>
    ...
</div></div>
```

This should work consistently across browsers without need to address IE9 speficically.

Comment: I'd still give the inside div a class or ID, but otherwise that's the way to go.

Comment: @user1337 IE6 generally does not matter currently, so extra class or id for nested element is unneeded.

Comment: it's not specifically for IE6 support but for performance and best practices.